# Save data to CSV and encode to utf-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, php-7

I have a database encoded as `utf8mb4`. I connect with this database and I set utf8 charset:

```
$dbHandler = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8mb4", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
```

All data is property encoded in DB. I want to fetch data and save it as CSV:

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w+');
foreach ($result as $row) {
...
    fputcsv($fp, $csvData, ';');
}
```

But then all the encoding is broken:
`groÃ<9f>e`, 
`ZubehÃ¶r.`  etc.

I've tried to add BOM (didn't help) and convert `array_map("utf8_encode", $csvData);` (some characters are displaying correct: `große`, `Zubehör`, but some not: `Kabelverl?ng`, `F?r`). Any idea?

## EDIT:

Hexdump output beginning of file:

```
00000000: efbb bf70 726f 6475 6374 3b61 7274 6963  ...product;artic
00000010: 6c65 3b73 6b75 3b64 6174 653b 6e61 6d65  le;sku;date;name
00000020: 0a30 3030 3239 3039 3530 3030 3b3b 3b3b  .00028151000;;;;
00000030: 2242 7265 616b 6f75 742d 626f 7820 4b70  "Breakout-box Kp
00000040: 6c2e 223b 223c 7374 726f 6e67 3e42 7265  l.";"<strong>Bre
00000050: 616b 6f75 742d 626f 7820 4b70 6c2e 3c2f  akout-box Kpl.</
```

Hexdump output of file with 1 record where we can see the issue (F..r instead of Für). By the way - original string was modified by ucwords and strtolower:

```
00000000: 3030 3032 3930 3936 3030 333b 3b3b 3b22  00028151000;;;;"
00000010: 4e65 747a 7465 696c 2032 3230 762f 3132  Netzteil 220v/12
00000020: 7620 46e3 9c72 2041 766c 223b 223c 7374  v F..r Avl";"<st
00000030: 726f 6e67 3e4e 6574 7a74 6569 6c20 3232  rong>Netzteil 22
00000040: 3076 2f31 3276 2046 e39c 7220 4176 6c3c  0v/12v F..r Avl<
00000050: 2f73 7472 6f6e 673e 3c62 723e 3c62 723e  /strong><br><br>
00000060: 4f45 4d20 4e75 6d6d 6572 3a20 3030 3032  OEM Nummer: 0002
00000070: 3930 3936 3030 3322 3b31 3038 2e34 363b  9096003";108.46;
00000080: 3030 3032 3930 3936 3030 332d 6e65 747a  00028151000-netz
00000090: 7465 696c 2d32 3230 762d 3132 762d 6675  teil-220v-12v-fu
000000a0: 722d 6176 6c3b 4875 7371 7661 726e 613b  r-avl;Husqvarna;
000000b0: 4452 4f50 444f 574e 3b59 3b4e 3b68 7474  DROPDOWN;Y;N;htt
000000c0: 7073 3a2f 2f73 7061 7265 7061 7274 7366  ps://sparepartsf
000000d0: 696e 6465 722e 6b74 6d2e 636f 6d2f 5350  inder.fha.com/SP
000000e0: 462f 496d 6167 6573 2f6d 6170 732f 3130  F/Images/maps/10
000000f0: 3030 3032 3932 302e 6769 663b 313b 4154  0002920.gif;1;AT
00000100: 3b57 6964 6765 743b 224b 544d 204f 7269  ;Ponret;"KTM Ori
00000110: 6769 6e61 6c20 4572 7361 747a 7465 696c  ginal Ersatzteil
00000120: 6522 3b22 4875 7371 7661 726e 6120 4e65  e";"Husqvarna Ne
00000130: 747a 7465 696c 2032 3230 762f 3132 7620  tzteil 220v/12v 
00000140: 46e3 9c72 2041 766c 202d 204f 454d 204e  F..r Avl - OEM N
00000150: 756d 6d65 723a 2030 3030 3239 3039 3630  ummer: 000290960
00000160: 3033 223b 3b22 4b61 7566 656e 2053 6965  03";;"Kaufen Sie
00000170: 2048 7573 7176 6172 6e61 204e 6574 7a74   Husqvarna Netzt
00000180: 6569 6c20 3232 3076 2f31 3276 2046 e39c  eil 220v/12v F..
00000190: 7220 4176 6c20 6d69 7420 4f45 4d2d 4e75  r Avl mit OEM-Nu
000001a0: 6d6d 6572 2030 3030 3239 3039 3630 3033  mmer 00028151000
000001b0: 2062 6569 2065 696e 656d 2048 7573 7176   bei einem Husqv
000001c0: 6172 6e61 2d56 6572 7472 6167 7368 c3a4  arna-Vertragsh..
000001d0: 6e64 6c65 722e 2057 6972 2068 6162 656e  ndler. Wir haben
000001e0: 2065 696e 6520 6772 6fc3 9f65 2041 7573   eine gro..e Aus
000001f0: 7761 686c 2061 6e20 4875 7371 7661 726e  wahl an Husqvarn
00000200: 612d 4572 7361 747a 7465 696c 656e 2c20  a-Ersatzteilen, 
00000210: 4163 6365 7373 6f72 6965 732c 2043 6c6f  Accessories, Clo
00000220: 7468 696e 672c 204d 5820 4265 6b6c 6569  thing, MX Beklei
00000230: 6475 6e67 2075 6e64 205a 7562 6568 c3b6  dung und Zubeh..
00000240: 722e 220a                                r.".
```

`file data.csv` output:

```
data.csv: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Comment: Is the encoding of the CSV file broken, or is your CSV editor not interpreting it correctly? Could you [edit] the question to add a hexdump of the CSV (not all of it, but the first six lines or so of `xxd file.csv` output.

Comment: I think it is... I checked in vim and Excel. Both have the same problem.

Comment: "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text" is suspicious. `file` should recognize UTF-8. And you're definitely starting with the UTF-8 BOM there. Could you maybe extend the hexdump to go as far as some of the characters with problems? (In my own experience, Excel works best with tab-delimited UTF-16 with BOM, rather than comma-delimited UTF-8 with or without BOM.)

Comment: I've generated csv and put only one line there. I attached hexdump to original post.

Comment: I just removed ucwords and strtolower and it worked! `file` gives me `data.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines` and encoding is correct.

Comment: 1. Work consistently with UTF-8. 
2. utf8_encode is only need if csv is from a ISO sorce
3. Use only the multibyte string functions.
The simple string functions are ASCII only and can destroy UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I would expect `F..r`, because it shows only ASCII characters there, but the hex should be `46 c3 bc 72` whereas you have `46 e3 9c 72`. This is because _ü_ in UTF-8 should be encoded as a two-byte sequence: `c3bc`.

Comment: See if the accepted answer can help you: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `strtolower` and `ucfirst`. I changed it to

```
$name = mb_convert_case($name, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
$name = mb_convert_case($name, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

and it works.